# Create array of points from single dimensional array of points

Tags: matlab

Waht i need to do is take a single dimensional array, ie:

```
[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]
```

and turn it into an array of points:

```
[[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]]
```

I am hoping for a simple native matlab way of doing it rather then a function. This will be going into sets of points ie:

```
[ [[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]],
  [[4, 4], [5, 5], [6, 6]],
  [[7, 7], [7, 7], [8, 8]] ]
```

The reason this is going to happen is the points will be stored in a text file as a single stream and i need to turn them into something meaningful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First note that a horizontal concatenation of row vectors will result in one larger row vector rather than in a row of pairs, that is `[[1, 1], [2, 2], [3, 3]]` is the same as `[1 1 2 2 3 3]`. Hence, you need to concatenate them vertically.

You can try

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3];

b = reshape(a, 2, floor(length(a)/2))';
```

This will result in a matrix where each row represents the coordinates of one point.

```
b =

     1     1
     2     2
     3     3
```

Comment: You could also use the third dimension to create the sets. So either you would take 3x2 vectors like b in the answer above and do something like SET = cat(b, AnotherB, 3) or else if it makes more sense to have the pairs going on the third dimension then change the reshape above to b = reshape(a, [2, 1, floor(length(a)/2)]) and then you can use normal vertical concatenation to create a set: SET = [b; AnotherB]

Answer (score 2):

I'm just adding this answer for the sake of diversity:

Just as H.Muster said, concatenation of vectors will result in a larger vector or a matrix (depending on your operation). You can go with that.

But you can also use a [cell array](http://www.mathworks.com/help/techdoc/matlab_prog/br04bw6-98.html), which is a set of data containers called "cells". A cell can contain any type of data, regradless of what other cells contain in the same cell array.

In your case, creating a cell array can be done using a slightly different syntax (than H.Muster's answer):

```
a = [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3];
p = mat2cell(a, 1, 2 * ones(1, numel(a) / 2))
```

`p` is a cell array, each cell containing a 1-by-2 point vector. To access an element in a cell array, you'll have to use curly braces. For instance, the second point would be `p{2} = [2, 2]`.